# Why conserve angular momentum about COM

Tags: angular-momentum, reference-frames, conservation-laws, collision, rigid-body-dynamics

In many questions involving collisions between Rigid bodies angular momentum is conserved about center of mass

If bodies stick together after collision they estimate com and then conserve about angular momentum about it why not any other point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *centre of mass* as a point about which **angular momentum** is conserved usually makes your work easy as the *pseudo force* and some other forces passes through *centre of mass* and so we can neglect them in terms of **angular momentum conservation**, but you can always use any point as per your convenience

Comment: No, this is dead wrong. You *can't* use arbitrary points at your convenience.

Comment: What I wanted to say was in some cases u can take another point in the space which get your work done